# Do many actions in a call in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

Now I work with Elasticsearch and I know how to reindex for an index: **Create new Index (with new mapping) --> Reindex --> Delete old index --> Set Alias for new index**. It means I have to call 4 times (I use curl or postman to call) to Elasticsearch to do all steps for reindex.

Is there any way to define or combine 4 calls into 1 call in Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for combining requests but you can select all 4 requests in kibana dev console and press Ctrl-Enter of Command-Enter or write a simple bash script that combines all 4 curl statements.